# Real world demand dataset

Tags: online-resources, data, demand-distribution

I am looking for a publicly available real world demand data to compare the performance of some algorithms. The dataset should include some products with data of a sufficiently long period of time. I know the [FoodMart](http://pentaho.dlpage.phi-integration.com/mondrian/mysql-foodmart-database) dataset, whose structure you can find described on [this page](https://github.com/julianhyde/foodmart-data-hsqldb); but, this dataset includes a small number of records per product so that it is not suitable for my purpose.

I appreciate any link to such dataset or papers which have made their dataset publicly available.

Comment: give a try to the google dataset search engine in this address: https://toolbox.google.com/datasetsearch

Comment: Kaggle has lots of datasets containing demand data, e.g., [here](https://www.kaggle.com/c/demand-forecasting-kernels-only/data). They are usually designed for forecasting/prediction, but I don't see why you can't use them for other purposes.

Comment: The [time series data library](https://pkg.yangzhuoranyang.com/tsdl/) from [Rob Hyndman](https://robjhyndman.com/) has hundreds (~648) of time-series data. It depends on what you call "demand," but I'm not sure how many meet your "*sufficiently long period of time*" criterion.

Comment: @OguzToragay Thanks !. I know the search engines. My question was mostly about a given known database that you are aware of.

Comment: @RyanCory-Wright  Thanks!. I am looking into the mentioned dataset. The problem with Kaggle is that there are a lot of dataset, and it might be time-consuming to understand and analyze each dataset to find a proper one.

Comment: @SecretAgentMan, Thanks. This looks fantastic. But, I could not find any description of each dataset. DO you know if there is one for each of the datasets?

Comment: @AfshinOroojlooy Yes! See [my answer](https://or.stackexchange.com/a/1314/491).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## Time Series Data Library

The [time series data library](https://pkg.yangzhuoranyang.com/tsdl/) from [Rob Hyndman](https://robjhyndman.com/) has hundreds (~648+) of time-series data. It depends on what you call "*demand*" and what you require as a "*sufficiently long period of time*."

The entire dataset has been migrated to an R package called **tsdl**. It is also available on [GitHub](https://github.com/FinYang/tsdl).

You can find descriptions of the data in the [meta data](https://pkg.yangzhuoranyang.com/tsdl/reference/meta_tsdl.html).

## Select examples:

**"Monthly demand repair parts large/heavy equip. Iowa 1972 – 1979"**
**"Montly av. residential gas usage Iowa (cubic feet)*100 ’71 – ’79"**
**"Monthly gasoline demand Ontario gallon millions 1960 – 1975"**
"Monthly sales of U.S. houses (thousands) 1965 – 1975"
**"Monthly Av. residential electricity usage Iowa city 1971 – 1979"**
**"Monthly car sales in Quebec 1960-1968"**
"Monthly U.S. housing starts (privately owned 1-family) 1965 – 1975"
"Four-weekly totals of beer shipments"
"Annual unit price of lynx pelts (Hudson’s Bay company, Canada) 1857 – 1911"
"Annual yield of straw on Broadbalk field at Rothamsted 1852-1925"
"Basic quarterly iron production in Australia: thousand tonnes. Mar 1956 – Sep 1994"
"Monthly beer production in Australia: megalitres."
"Quarterly beer production in Australia: megalitres. March 1956 – June 1994"

---

There is another way to see data descriptions:

The [raw data](https://github.com/FinYang/tsdl/tree/master/data-raw) is also available. If you [drill down](https://github.com/FinYang/tsdl/tree/master/data-raw/monthly), there is a ***README.txt*** for each one (e.g. example for ["monthly"](https://github.com/FinYang/tsdl/tree/master/data-raw/monthly)). These text files are viewable on GitHub in your browser.